# How to view movies frame by frame or move smoothly through a video sequence (golf swing!)

Tags: video, video-playback

How do I control display of a movie so I can move it smoothly through a sequence and stop at any point?  I have a Go Pro that can take 400 frames/sec and a video cam that takes ? frames/sec, but all I can do is hit Start/Stop real fast to try to stop it where I want to, or move a few frames farther on.  Specifically, I'm talking about viewing my golf swing, and I see them do it all the time on TV or on the instructional videos on line.  Do I have to buy a special video viewer to do this?  Does the GoPro suite have a feature to do this that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

[VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/index.html) can do it [freeware, all platforms]

Using default key-commands, can be changed in prefs.

Spacebar to pause
ctrl, alt or shift plus arrow key to jump differing amounts back & forwards to get the right start point
E key will then frame-by-frame

Comment: Should be noted that you can't move *backwards*, just one frame forward at a time.

Comment: True - I hadn't noticed that... but you can do 'very short jump' in either direction, which is 1 second.

Comment: … which is 400 frames in the case of the OP :) I think there was a plugin for VLC which allowed to do frame-by-frame skipping, also backwards, but it's not compatible with the latest release.